# Java. How to add text to each line

Tags: java

I need to add in loop text at the end of each line in the file.

For example, my file look like:

```
Adam
Maria
Jon
```

Now in loop, I need to add next columns, to look like:

```
Adam|Kowalski
Maria|Smith
Jon|Jons
```

3rd column:

```
Adam|Kowalski|1999
Maria|Smith|2013
Jon|Jons|1983
```

And so on. How to do that effectively ? **One limit of my program is**, that i dont know all of the new value to add, I mean i **can't** write "**|Kowalski|1999**" at once, need to write "|Kowalski" then in add "|1999"

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {// for test I throw the Exception to keep code shorter.
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String path = "the/path/to/file";
    BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
    String line;
    while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
        line += "|"+"the-text-to-add"+"\n\r";
        sb.append(line);
    }
    bReader.close();

    // now write it back to the file
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(path));
    out.write(sb.toString().getBytes());
    out.close();
}
```